# Why does SimpleAudioEngine behave differently on each platform, and is there a way to configure it?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am using SimpleAudioEngine to play sound effects on my app. It works on Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal), Android, and iOS. But I noticed the following behaviour which is not consistent:

1. In iOS, if I am listen to music on the Apple Music app, and then I launch my game, the music is silenced.
2. In Android, the music from Google Play is continued to be played even after launching my app. I can also hear the sound effects from my game.
3. In Windows Phone the behaviour is the same as Android.
   Why is it different for iOS, and is there some way this can be configured ?

I am using cocos2d-x v3.7 (C++)

Comment: The audio engine in Cocos2d-x is definitely less than perfect. That comment is valid for the SimpleAudioEngine and the new AudioEngine. I have tried contributing some code to it, but it is a challenge because each platform has different base audio systems to work with. If there are not already issues created for these in github, then I suggest creting them. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, SimpleAudioEngine uses a different codebase, and the default settings in CDAudioManager are to play effects and music (only if no other music is playing). If you edit the CDAudioManager code you can change the default settings of SimpleAudioEngine, or alternatively, just use CDAudioManager on iOS.